# ZeroMQ PUSH / PULL - how to know which events are pending in SEND BUFFER queue?

Tags: zeromq

We have a service pair doing `PUSH/PULL` pattern of message communication. As mentioned in the docs, if the `PULL` service is down or not running, then a sender will queue up to high water mark number of events and by default a `.send()` after that will block.

Now, while an app is in the blocking state, the app could be killed or something else may happen, leading up to loosing those messages in the queue.

I understand `PUSH/PULL` is not the best method if we want that kind of reliability and should probably use some of the other method listed at: https://zguide.zeromq.org/docs/chapter4/ but is there a way in `PUSH/PULL` method to get event call back on the events still on queue on say app exit/periodic callbacks/signals?

I also understand, that I could use `NOBLOCK` or `ZMQ_IMMEDIATE` or `ZMQ_SNDTIMEO` in such situation and catch the error and use application level recovery (similar to DLQ pattern) but I was looking into things available from the ZeroMQ library.

Answer (score 0):

> **Q :** <sub>*"... how to know which events are pending in SEND BUFFER queue ?"*</sub>

**A :**
Well,
having used ZeroMQ since v2.1, v3.x, till v4.x in 2022-Q1, there has never been a way, how a user-level code may interact with ZeroMQ internal queues and/or state(s) as there was no such method in c-API to do so.

> **Q :** <sub>*"... is there a way in `PUSH/PULL` method to get event call back on the events still on queue on say app exit/periodic callbacks/signals?*"</sub>

**A :**
Well,
 let's solve this by using a concurrently operated signalling-socket, for receiving POSACK-messages from "live"-clients, i.e. those, that can and do receive messages - thus being able to back-throttle messages for those, that did not respond in reasonable TAT. Using a mix of several, properly selected Scalable Formal Communications Patterns archetypes to work in cooperation, helps solve this "soft"-signalling control. Without an ambition to solve all details, a set of one-`PUB.bind()` / many-`SUB.connect()`-sockets for selectively directed payload-transport with subscription-based controls and one-`PULL.bind()` / many-`PUSH.connect()`-s for "soft"-control signalling of still-alive-heartbeats, traffic back-throttling and similar services